# Сегментно-страничная организация памяти для файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, память

У меня есть три .json файла, которые нужно хранить в памяти сегментно-страничной организацией. Прочёл несколько статей на просторе интернета и там рассказывают о плюсах и минусах подобной организации, а в середине статьи представлена страшная схема реализации. Прошу вас помочь мне разобраться с этим вопросом, если есть возможность, покажите, пожалуйста, реализацию на python.

Comment: При программировании на языках высокого уровня, таких как Python, не приходится заниматься столь низкоуровневыми вопросами, как организация виртуальной памяти.

Comment: Либо вы не до конца понимаете, что такое страничная организация памяти, и это совсем не то, что вам нужно. Либо понимаете правильно, но это все равно вряд ли то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, знаю, но препод дал такое доп.задание и тут ни как неотвертеться

Comment: Именно на Python дал задание реализовать?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, изначально было задание связанное с парсом вк, многопоточностью и т.д. (Сделал всё) для этого решил выбрать python, а сегодня препод дал второе-последние задание с организацией памяти. Когда выбирал python,  то не знал, что так будет

Comment: Тогда смотрите в сторону [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mmap.html), не зная конкретного задания, больше особо и предложить нечего.

Comment: @extrn, спасибо. Задание, принципе, звучало как я его написал, если возникнут идеи, то отпишись, пожалуйста

Comment: Такие вещи делаются на Ассемблере или C, причём или в коде ядра операционной системы или вообще на голом железе.

Comment: Понял, тогда почитаю о mmap, как посоветовал extrn

Comment: Это и есть идея: mmap постранично подгружает файл в память, и позволяет работать с ним как с участком памяти. А подойдет ли эта идея в качестве решения, без более конкретно описанного задания невозможно. Выясняйте у преподавателя.

Comment: @extrn, спрошу, но всё равно попытаюсь воспользоваться mmap, если что-то получится, то отпишусь, спасибо вам